# How to put text below images

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the text appear below the zoomed images but they keep on appearing at the back and the images seem to eat up all the space in the post body.

When I try to use `<p></p>` , the text is outside of the text body.

I use a Blogger blog and I just copied the code from Krz Szzz codepen: https://codepen.io/ccrch/pen/yyaraz.

HTML

```
<div class="tiles">
    <div class="tile" data-scale="1.1" data-image="http://ultraimg.com/images/0yS4A9e.jpg"></div>
    <div class="tile" data-scale="1.6" data-image="http://ultraimg.com/images/hzQ2IGW.jpg"></div>
    <div class="tile" data-scale="2.4" data-image="http://ultraimg.com/images/bNeWGWB.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:700);
    body {
        background: #fff;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .tiles {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .tile {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 33.333%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .photo {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        transition: transform .5s ease-out;
    }

    .txt {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 10%;
        left: 0;
        font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
        font-size: 9px;
        line-height: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: default;
    }

    .x {
        font-size: 32px;
        line-height: 32px;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using some framework? You didn't tag appropriately.

Comment: Hello madam, I tried to use <p> inside and outside the <div> but the text still appear on the back, and the whole images cover the date, also the text are reaching the comment section...really confused what tag to use. I am using an Emporio theme because it has grid layout.

Comment: I meant do you use angularjs or something similar?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of whats happening: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-3ZZ7wtpiPP0/Wx-UAQL0M7I/AAAAAAAAC9c/f1TAHFRVbBIdyRk8ajzCW4GlbbHdq9dTwCLcBGAs/s1600/zoom%2Bimages.jpg

Comment: Hello madam, I'm not familiar with angularjs. I only copied the codes and try if it will work with Blogger blog. Its just confusing what tag should I use to make the text go down and not exceed the comment box.

Answer (score 1):

Added these 2 styles with new properties

```
  .photo {
    height: 80%;
  }

  .txt {
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

Removed absolute, top, bottom from the following

```
.photo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: transform .5s ease-out;
  }

  .txt {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    font-size: 9px;
    line-height: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
  }
```

See updated [coedpen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzdRVy)

```css
 

  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:700);

  body {
background: #fff;
color: #000;
margin: 0;
  }

  .tiles {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
  }

  .tile {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 33.333%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
  }

  .photo {
width: 100%;
height: 80%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
transition: transform .5s ease-out;
  }

  .txt {
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
font-size: 9px;
line-height: 12px;
text-align: center;
cursor: default;
  }

  .x {
font-size: 32px;
line-height: 32px;
  }
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <div class="tiles">
<div class="tile" data-scale="1.1" data-image="http://ultraimg.com/images/0yS4A9e.jpg"></div>
<div class="tile" data-scale="1.6" data-image="http://ultraimg.com/images/hzQ2IGW.jpg"></div>
<div class="tile" data-scale="2.4" data-image="http://ultraimg.com/images/bNeWGWB.jpg"></div>
  </div>

<script>

  $('.tile')
// tile mouse actions
.on('mouseover', function(){
  $(this).children('.photo').css({'transform': 'scale('+ $(this).attr('data-scale') +')'});
})
.on('mouseout', function(){
  $(this).children('.photo').css({'transform': 'scale(1)'});
})
.on('mousemove', function(e){
  $(this).children('.photo').css({'transform-origin': ((e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) / $(this).width()) * 100 + '% ' + ((e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) / $(this).height()) * 100 +'%'});
})
// tiles set up
.each(function(){
  $(this)
    // add a photo container
    .append('<div class="photo"></div>')
    // some text just to show zoom level on current item in this example
    .append('<div class="txt"><div class="x">'+ $(this).attr('data-scale') +'x</div>ZOOM ON<br>HOVER</div>')
    // set up a background image for each tile based on data-image attribute
    .children('.photo').css({'background-image': 'url('+ $(this).attr('data-image') +')'});
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check in full view

```js
$('.tile')
    // tile mouse actions
    .on('mouseover', function(){
      $(this).find('.photoin').css({'transform': 'scale('+ $(this).attr('data-scale') +')'});
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(){
      $(this).find('.photoin').css({'transform': 'scale(1)'});
    })
    .on('mousemove', function(e){
      $(this).find('.photoin').css({'transform-origin': ((e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) / $(this).width()) * 100 + '% ' + ((e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) / $(this).height()) * 100 +'%'});
    })
    // tiles set up
    .each(function(){
      $(this)
        // add a photo container
        .append('<div class="photo"><div class="photoin"></div></div>')
        // some text just to show zoom level on current item in this example
        .append('<div class="txt"><div class="x">'+ $(this).attr('data-scale') +'x</div>ZOOM ON<br>HOVER</div>')
        // set up a background image for each tile based on data-image attribute
        .find('.photoin').css({'background-image': 'url('+ $(this).attr('data-image') +')'});
   
    })
```

```css
body { margin:0; padding:0;}
  body {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .tiles {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .tile {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
 .photoin { position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0;  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover; transition: transform .5s ease-out;}
  .photo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    bottom:150px; overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: transform .5s ease-out;
  }

  .txt {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    font-size: 9px;
    line-height: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
  }

  .x {
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="tiles">
     <div class="tile" data-scale="1.1" data-image="http://ultraimg.com/images/0yS4A9e.jpg"></div>
     <div class="tile" data-scale="1.6" data-image="http://ultraimg.com/images/hzQ2IGW.jpg"></div>
     <div class="tile" data-scale="2.4" data-image="http://ultraimg.com/images/bNeWGWB.jpg"></div>
   </div>
```

Please check in full view